# How to prove A△B=B△A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Problem : Prove the following properties of the symmetric difference: 
          A△B=B△A

Comment: How has $\Delta$ been defined?

Comment: Do you know that unions commute?

Comment: A△B=(A∪B)∖(B∩A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\triangle B=(A\cup B)\setminus (B\cap A)=(A\cup B)\cap (B\cap A)^c=(A\cup B)\cap (B^c\cup A^c)\\=(B\cup A)\cap (A^c\cup B^c)=(B\cup A)\cap (A\cap B)^c\\=(B\cup A)\setminus (A\cap B)=B\triangle A$$